# Sheet appears without animation on Pro Max phone when in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui

iPhone/iPad app with `NavigationSplitView`. So, Sidebar on left, Content in middle and Detail on the right. I have a button in the Content toolbar and another button on the Detail view that each display the same sheet. On a Pro Max phone in landscape the Content toolbar button produces the sheet with no bottom up animation. Dismiss animates away as expected. All other devices and orientations seem fine.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SheetShooterApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                SidebarView()
            } content: {
                ContentView()
            } detail: {
                DetailView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List { Text("Hello") }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPatternSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        List { Text("Hello, again") }
        .navigationTitle("Patterns")
        .toolbar { contentViewToolbarContent() }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPatternSheet) { PatternSheet() }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder func contentViewToolbarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button { showPatternSheet = true } label: { Image(systemName: "plus") }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var showPatternSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Details")
        Button("New Pattern") { showPatternSheet = true }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPatternSheet) { PatternSheet() }
    }
}

struct PatternSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("New Pattern Sheet").toolbar { patternSheetToolbarContent() }
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder func patternSheetToolbarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button { dismiss() } label: { Text("Done") }
        }
    }
}
```

I hopefully haven't cut down the reproducible example too far.

The button in the Detail view works right across the board, it's just the toolbar button in the Content view that has a problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the slideover split view

Comment: If you use `.navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)` to always show the split it fixes it.

Comment: Yes, looks like you're right about the slideover. Also right about the `.navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)` but that introduces unpleasant UI constraints on the smaller devices. I ended up going with a single `.sheet` on the Detail view and moving the sheet's `@State` property back up the view tree and having both buttons set this same property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth and as per my comment above:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SheetShooterApp: App {
    @State private var showPatternSheet = false
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationSplitView {
                SidebarView()
            } content: {
                ContentView(showPatternSheet: $showPatternSheet)
            } detail: {
                DetailView(showPatternSheet: $showPatternSheet)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List { Text("Hello") }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
//    @State private var showPatternSheet = false
    @Binding var showPatternSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {
        List { Text("Hello, again") }
            .navigationTitle("Patterns")
            .toolbar { contentViewToolbarContent() }
//            .sheet(isPresented: $showPatternSheet) { PatternSheet() }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder func contentViewToolbarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button { showPatternSheet = true } label: { Image(systemName: "plus") }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
//    @State private var showPatternSheet = false
    @Binding var showPatternSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("Details")
        Button("New Pattern") { showPatternSheet = true }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPatternSheet) { PatternSheet() }
    }
}

struct PatternSheet: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("New Pattern Sheet").toolbar { patternSheetToolbarContent() }
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder func patternSheetToolbarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button { dismiss() } label: { Text("Done") }
        }
    }
}
```